# How Can I calculate the difference of age between 2 objects?

Tags: java

I am learning JAVA OOP, I have to compare the age between 2 objects:

In java Procedural, I will have done:

```
public static int calculateDifferenceAge(int agePlayer1, int agePlayer2){
      int differenceAge = agePlayer1 - agePlayer2;

      if(differenceAge < 0){
        differenceAge = -differenceAge;
      }
      return differenceAge; 
}
```

Then

```
public static void displayDifferenceAge(String namePlayer1, String namePlayer2, int agePlayer1, int agePlayer2){
      System.out.println("Age difference between " + namePlayer1 + " and " + namePlayer2 + " is of" + calculateDifferenceAge(agePlayer1, agePlayer2) + " year(s).");
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to create my calculateDifferenceAge() method in OOP ?

In my main file I have this:

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList <Player>();
players.add(new Player("Eric", 31, true));
players.add(new Player("Juliette", 27, false));
```

I am stuck into my 2 methods:

How to subtract the age of 2 objects?

```
public static int calculateAgeDifference(List <Player> players){

    Player differenceAge = (players.get(0) - players.get(1));

    return differenceAge; 

  }

  public static void displayCalculateAgeDifference(List <Player> players){
    System.out.println(calculateAgeDifference().age);
  }
```

Class Player

```
public class Player {

  public String name;
  public int age;
  public boolean sex;

  public Player(String name, int age, boolean sex){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.sex = sex;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're only missing a little step in your code. The steps to extract the ages of the list should be:

1.- Extract the object from the list

2.- Extract the age of that object (or player, in this case)

3.- Substract the ages

There's some ways to do it, but I would do it this way:

```
public static int calculateAgeDifference(List<Player> players) {
    int age1= players.get(0).age;
    int age2= players.get(1).age;

    int differenceAge = age1 - age2;

    if(differenceAge < 0){
        differenceAge = -differenceAge;
    }
    return differenceAge;
}
```

I hope that helps. What i've done there is extract the objects player from the list: **players.get(0)** extracts the first object inside the list, which is a Player. Now that I have a player and it has an age variable i have to extract it with **player.age**. I collapsed those steps, if you have any questions I can explain you further

Display method:

```
 public static int displayCalculateAgeDifference (List<Player> players){
    String name1= players.get(0).name;
    String name2= players.get(1).name;
    
    //as you know this method return the difference in a number form
    int difference= calculateAgeDifference(players);

    System.out.println("Age difference between " + name1 + " and " + name2 + " is of" + difference + " year(s).");
}
```

Comment: You're right, i'll edit it. I was using arrays when I saw the question and my brain didn't switch haha

Comment: I see you asked for an adaptation of the display method, i added it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with a class `Player`. Let's give it a `name` and an `age`, and a `calculateAgeDifference` method. It should look something like,

```
public class Player {
    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Player(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int calculateAgeDifference(Player player2) {
        return Math.abs(this.age - player2.age);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
Player a = new Player("Eric", 40);
Player b = new Player("Sally", 51);
System.out.println(a.calculateAgeDifference(b));
```

You must have a similar `Player` class. Yours appears to also have a `boolean` field. It isn't clear why. So I can't speak to that.

Comment: Thank you Elliott Frisch for your explanation and your help.

Answer (score 2):

Why did your method interface change from two parameters to a list? You can still pass two instances of the object. You can still return the integer age value from the method, no need to create a Frankenstein's Player instance only to hold the age.

I am assuming your `Player` class has a method `getAge()` to extract the age value which was passed in in the constructor:

```java
public static int calcAgeDiff(final Player player1, final Player player2) {
  int age1 = player1.getAge();
  int age2 = player2.getAge();
  return Math.abs(age2 - age1);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add an instance method to your Player class itself to calculate the age difference to a different player:

```java
public class Player {
  // fields
  // constructor
  // getters
  public int ageDiffTo(final Player otherPlayer) {
    return Math.abs(this.age - otherPlayer.age); // <- a class can always access its private fields, even of other instances
  }
}
```

then call as `player1.ageDiffTo(player2)`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I would like to do with an arrayList, it's in my learning in JAVA OOP.

Comment: @eric in that case, extract the players of the list like you already do and then compare their age. You are almost there, combine the first half of your method with the second half of my method and voilà.

Comment: Merci Knittl it's ok now ^^